# Accessing vector of objects C++

Tags: c++, vector

Say I store a vector of objects. The object has an attribute such as int age which is private and we need to access it via getAge().

Lets say we call the object "people"

I store the object "people" in a vector...
soo...

```
 vector<people> vectorOfPeople
```

My question is...
Is it possible to directly access the 'age' via the vector vectorOfPeople?
Maybe something like `vectorOfPeople[0].getAge()` or something... (I know that doesn't work).

Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't that work? That's exactly how you do it.

Comment: I second @Kerrek. If you want a better answer, ask a better question. A start would be to show us `people`, so that we can see how a person's age is defined.

Answer (score 6):

Doing what you said should work:

```
// Make a vector of people
vector<people> pVec;
// Stick a people (person?) in it
pVec.push_back(people(someAge, someName)); // Or whatever constructor you have
// Show the age
cout << pVec[0].getAge(); // This should print out the age assigned in the c'tor
```

The name you chose is a bit unintuitive in this case, but otherwise you should have no problems.

Answer (score 1):

The std::vector has operators:

```
reference operator[] ( size_type n );
const_reference operator[] ( size_type n ) const;
```

They,
**Return a reference to the element at position n in the vector container.**

So, `vectorOfPeople[0]` would return a reference to the element at `0`th position in the vector container and then `getAge()` will be called on that reference object.

It is nothing different than,

```
people obj;
obj.getAge();
```